# Determining repository and aggregate size and responsibility in DDD architecture

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

A concrete (i hope) question  that I would love a concrete answer to if possible... in regards to DDD architecture of aggregates and repository responsibility and fine-grain level.

**Lets say I have following (simplified) tables:**

- customer [id, name, groupId, categoryId]
- customerGroup [id, name]
- customerCategory [id, name]

**Basic functionality (just to show example usage of methods)**

Show customer list and click to show one customer. 
Edit customer and select group from a dropdownlist of all groups. And the same for cateogry.

**Question**

Should I consider customer group and category as separate aggregates with:

- CustomerRepository. With methods GetAllCustomers, GetCustomerById etc
- CustomerGroupRepository. With methods GetAllCustomerGroups, GetOneCustomerGroup
- CustomerCategoryRepository. With methods GetAllCustomerCategories, GetOneCustomerCategory

Or only **one repo**
- CustomerRepository (with all above methods, more explicitly named).

Layer above will either case be one CustomerService with one/many repos above injected.

I would love some input to how to think in regards to size of aggregate and related data (categories, groups) with pros/cons of fine-grained repositories or not. Still keeping it simple and focusing on solving problems in a good way without over-architecturing stuff.

I've tried to find similar examples here on SO and also read vaughn vernon's articles but did not for example see how his example of product aggregate handled product categories.

Answer (score 6):

There is no specific aggregate model to derive from this domain since it is mostly hierarchical. You basically just have dumb data structures inside containers inside other containers. No invariants or business rules in sight, no hint of parts that will be under significant concurrent access.

If that's all there is to this domain, I wouldn't bother using the DDD tactical patterns to model it, it's just CRUD.

As the book title goes by, DDD is about tackling *complexity* in software, not pulling your hair out unnecessarily on simple problems.

Comment: I totally agree to not over-engineer something. In this case, there is more to it, this is part of a rather (too) large application where DDD repos and services already is used and have quite some business rules. But I do like your point and I will try to see if parts of context can be CRUD to keep this simple, without diverging from set architecture in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Can a user create a category without having any customers in it? If you answer yes, then the category is root aggregate and should have an own repository.

Same goes for Customer Groups. If they are just a sort of value that you tag the customer with it's a child aggregate (or rather a value object, compare with tags). If you should be able to create groups independently and then attach customers to them, you should define them as a root aggregate.

Comment: Great pin-point question, thank you. Answer is no at this time - hence I will keep it simple in one repo for now. If this changes - then a refactor will follow.